# Alfresco community 4.0 - Google docs integration?

Tags: alfresco, google-docs, alfresco-share

I want to know whether google docs integration with alfresco community version 4.0 is possible?
I could learn from the internet that it works with 3.0 and 5.0 Community. But, not sure about 4.0.
Please let me know if anyone has done or observed.

Comment: are you really talking about 4.0 and not about 4.1 or 4.2?

Comment: yes, community version 4.0

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation the integration exists (http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/at-googledocs-integration.html and subarticles).

1. First you need to create a google connection User between GoogleDocs and Alfresco.
2. You will then need to add this user through the Share UI in the Admin Console. You should see a GoogleDocs button. 
   Click on it and you should see three fields (enable, user, password)
3. Fill these fields accordingly to your needs

Now a small question why use this old version of Alfresco?

Comment: thanks @sgirardin, for answer, but I am looking for community edition.

Comment: there is requirement from clients that they wanted to integrate gdocs with alfresco without migrating from community version 4.0

Comment: @vikash I don't have a Community 4.0 under my hand but  almost certain you have the same behaviour then in the enterprise version.

Comment: sorry, but in community version  in Share UI in the Admin Console there is no any GoogleDocs button or any configuration link.

Comment: @vikash It seems you were able to find a way but google authentification methods are oudated in that Alfresco version...
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675903/how-to-integrate-google-docs-with-alfresco-community-4-0/43924304#43924304)